# String Manipulation for a text extracted with a css selector

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a code to extract multiple information regarding movies. I have a problem with manipulating one of the strings :

```
 '\n'
              '\t\t\t\t85\xa0mins \xa0\n'
              '\t\t\t\t\n'
              '\t\t\t\t\tMore details at\n'
              '\t\t\t\t\t'
```

I want to extract the duration of the movie, which, in this case, is the number 85.

I don't really know how to extract it since the format is pretty weird. My web scraping program yields items as dictionaries, for example:

```
{'film_director': ['Alfred Hitchcock'],
 'film_rating': ['4.0'],
 'film_time': '\n'
              '\t\t\t\t81\xa0mins \xa0\n'
              '\t\t\t\t\n'
              '\t\t\t\t\tMore details at\n'
              '\t\t\t\t\t',
 'film_title': ['Rope'],
 'film_year': ['1948']}
```

I have tried splitting it, but it doesn't seem to work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
film_dict = {'film_director': ['Alfred Hitchcock'],
 'film_rating': ['4.0'],
 'film_time': '\n'
              '\t\t\t\t81\xa0mins \xa0\n'
              '\t\t\t\t\n'
              '\t\t\t\t\tMore details at\n'
              '\t\t\t\t\t',
 'film_title': ['Rope'],
 'film_year': ['1948']}

film_time = (film_dict ['film_time'].replace ('\t', '')[: 7])
print (film_time)
```

Line eleven takes the film time value, removes the tab character and the truncates it to just the part that you need. The replace method replaces '\n' with nothing which just removes it. [:7] slices from the beginning of the modified string up to character number 8.